# FireDac DApt 400

Tags: mysql, primary-key, delphi-xe6, firedac

I use "XE6" and "MySQL" database. I have only one table. The primary key is auto increment. When I insert a record it generates an error: "[FireDac] [DApt] -400. Fetch command fecthed [0] instead of [1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Tracing_and_Monitoring_(FireDAC)) record. Another user ".

My table has primary key and there is no other connection to the database. Anyone have any idea what that might be?

My code:

```
AbrirConexao; // Open connection
fQryTransacao.Close;
fQryTransacao.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM APOLICE LIMIT 0'; // I dont use a script SQL. I load the structure of table. Then I enter the table.
fQryTransacao.Open;
fQryTransacao.Insert;
CarregarQuery(pApolice, fQryTransacao); // It takes the value of an object and assigns it in the "fields" of the query.
fQryTransacao.Post; // Here it generates the error.
EncerrarConexao; // Close connection
```

I used "TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink" to monitor the SQL commands. The generated LOG file has the generated "insert" command. If I copy and execute directly in "MySQL" does not generate error.

[Tracing and Monitoring (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Tracing_and_Monitoring_(FireDAC))

Comment: You have shown us far too little info. You say the SQL in generated well... but maybe in the log there is some other clue of what is going wrong. The fact the the key is autoincrement and that FireDac is complaining about a Fetch command makes me think that it's trying to retrieve the key value the server used on the insert. This is possibile, but not always useful. We really have too little to go on here.

Comment: In the LOG file this problem occurs: "When an application assigns values to parameters, the exact loss may happen. As a result of that, the WHERE phrase returns no records". I found the explanation of the error on this [site](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/Editing_Questions_(FireDAC)).
I checked and tested all the suggestions, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: An INSERT does not use a WHERE clause. Something else is happening and is going wrong... and you are not providing enough info for us.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: I think you should start with the log. It probably contains the answer.

Comment: I recreate the table and it worked. Probably must have been corrupted or something.